# Evil-emacs: how to make search/replace (:s/) global by default?

Tags: evil, replace

Vim has the following setting:

```
:help gdefault

When on, the ":substitute" flag 'g' is default on.  This means that
all matches in a line are substituted instead of one.  When a 'g' flag
is given to a ":substitute" command, this will toggle the substitution
of all or one match.
```

How do I get this behavior in `evil-emacs`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a variable named: `evil-ex-substitute-global`

If you check it with C-h v, it will give you the explanation:

> If non-nil substitute patterns a global by default. Hide    Usually
>   (if this variable is nil) a substitution works only on    the first
>   match of a pattern in a line unless the 'g' flag is    given, in which
>   case the substitution happens on all matches in a    line. If this
>   option is non-nil, this behaviour is reversed: the    substitution
>   works on all matches unless the 'g' pattern is    specified, then is
>   works only on the first match.

Hope this helps.